# Firebase dependencies not automatically upgraded with flutter pub upgrade

Tags: flutter, firebase

Running `flutter pub upgrade`, `flutter pug upgrade --major-versions` or `flutter packages upgrade` doesn't seem to upgrade my firebase dependencies at all. The last time I updated these dependencies was 9 months ago but it still won't update.

These are my dependencies at the moment:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^2.3.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.1.4
  webview_flutter: ^4.2.2
  cloud_firestore: ^4.1.0
  qr_flutter: ^4.0.0
  qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.1
  audioplayers: ^5.1.0
  vibration: ^1.7.6
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.11.0
  page_transition: ^2.0.2
  firebase_storage: ^11.0.6
  url_launcher: ^6.0.9
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.0.6
  firebase_analytics: ^10.0.6
  easy_localization: ^3.0.0
  flutter_markdown: ^0.6.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  introduction_screen: ^3.0.2
  wakelock: ^0.6.1+2
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  package_info_plus: ^3.0.2
  badges: ^3.1.1
  hooks_riverpod: ^2.1.1
  flutter_hooks: ^0.20.0
```

I would expect some kind of output which tells me if there is any dependency constraint, but I get nothing like that. I would also expect some kind of documentation on upgrading firebase dependencies but I find none. It feels as if I am missing something that should be quite obvious here.

I've tried finding documentation on upgrading or migrations for the flutter firebase sdks. I've tried running upgrade commands and `flutter pub outdated` which only gives me the following output:

```
Showing outdated packages.
[*] indicates versions that are not the latest available.

Package Name            Current   Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest  

direct dependencies:   
flutter_launcher_icons  *0.11.0   *0.11.0     *0.11.0     0.13.1  
package_info_plus       *3.1.2    *3.1.2      *3.1.2      4.1.0   
vibration               *1.7.7    *1.7.7      *1.7.7      1.8.1   

dev_dependencies:      
flutter_native_splash   *2.2.0+1  *2.2.0+1    *2.2.0+1    2.3.2   
You are already using the newest resolvable versions listed in the 'Resolvable' column.
Newer versions, listed in 'Latest', may not be mutually compatible.
```